# How to check database between two specific date with EF?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I would like to offer user get a report of orders from two specific dates(start-end). I want to calculate amount product(incl price) that were ordered within that period.

This is about what I had in mind:

```
 public ActionResult GetReport(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
        {    
            var getReport = db.Orders.Where(/*Date that matches between start and end time*/);

            //calculate the amount of each products(incl price) 

            return View(reportViewModel);       
        }
```

order-table:

```
    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public System.Guid UserId { get; set; }     
    public System.DateTime Ordered { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

Also, how do I send selected date-value from View to Controller (MVC) ?

Comment: `.Where(x + x.Ordered >= startTime && x.Ordered <= endTime)` (may need `x.Ordered < endTime.AddDays(1)` depending on if the date has a time compnent in the db)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I see. Thanks :)

Comment: That should have been `.Where(x => x.Ordered ...`.But I suspect there is more to it if your wanting to _calculate the amount of each products(incl price)_